# How do I make my activity on my work Github appear on my personal Github page?

Tags: github, github-pages

I commit to my work Github account (Github.com/work) and my personal account (Github.com/personal). How do I get activity from my work account to appear on my personal account?

There are periods where my personal account looks inactive although I've been committing to work repos. I don't want people viewing my personal page to get the wrong impression!

Comment: You'd have to merge them to one account: https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Using-one-account-for-all-your-projects/ba-p/5509

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is that the only way? Merging requires deleting one of the accounts.

Comment: Well, otherwise they're two accounts, with two different sets of activity.